# Django - can not access session

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-sessions

Using Django REST Framework in development, I have the following (previously working) code example, where in one view I set session data, and in another view I use that data.

And like I said, this code used to work, but now for some reason the stored session data can not be accessed anymore.

View for setting session data

```
@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes((AllowAny, ))
def set_session_data(request):
    session_data_dict = loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    if not isinstance(session_data_dict, dict):
        return Response({"message": "Expected a JSON object with key-val pairs to be sent. Key-val pairs to be set to session. Received something else.", status: status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST})
    try:
        for key, value in session_data_dict.items():
            request.session[key] = value
        response_data = {"status": rest_status.HTTP_200_OK}
    except:
        response_data = {"status": rest_status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR}
    return Response(response_data)
```

View that accesses stored session data:

```
@api_view(["GET"])
@permission_classes((AllowAny, ))
def check_user_logged_in(request):
    try:
        data = {"login_token": request.session["login_token"]}
    except KeyError:
        data = {"login_token": ""}
    return Response(data, status=rest_status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I have tested a little, and I can access the data in the session in the `set_session_data` view, after it has been added, like so:

`request.session['login_token']`

But when I try the same in the `check_user_logged_in` view, I get a `KeyError`.

So I tried checking if the sessions for both views are the same session, by checking the value of `request.COOKIES[settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME]` in each view. But in both views that results in the following error:

`KeyError: 'sessionid'`

Now, I have not touched the session settings, so they are the default settings from `django-admin startproject`. (`'django.contrib.sessions'` in `INSTALLED_APPS`, `'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'` in `MIDDLEWARE`, and nothing added.)

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Can you show us the `session_data_dict` content ?

Comment: Yes, it comes through properly: `{'login_token': '9ca81613821544db593d3bbf73cd1e7b3fb82bcc', 'user_id': '21'}`.

Comment: What is the output of `request.session`in both views ?

Comment: request.session in `set_session_data` function: `<django.contrib.sessions.backends.db.SessionStore object at 0x7fe901ebcfd0>`, request.session in `check_user_logged_in` function
`<django.contrib.sessions.backends.db.SessionStore object at 0x7fe901ebcbe0>`. The hash-like characters at the end, they are both different. My guess is that this means that both views (request) have a different session.

Comment: Today my code seems to be working. For some reason unaware to myself. Maybe something changed in the process of turning off my computer, along with the dev servers. and starting it all up again?